# Ejemplo de clases en python

Tags: python, herencia, class

Estoy intentando realizar el siguiente enunciado en python, a través de clases y subclases, saben cual sería el procedimiento a este plateamineto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esta va a ser tu clase abstracta y sobre esta haras las otras

```
class dispositivo():
     __init__(self,nombre,caracteresticas):
              self.nombre = nombre
              for caracteristica in caracterestica:
                     self.caracteristica.append(caracteristica)

     def imprimir(self):
         print(f"mi nombre es  {self.nombre}")
         for caracteristica in caracterestica:
                     print(f"caracteristica {caracteristica}")
```

luego hacemos las especificas

```
class especifica1(dispositivo):
      def __init__(self,nombre,caracteristicas):
                 self.super().__init__(nombre,caracteristicas)

class especifica2(dispositivo):
      def __init__(self,nombre,caracteristicas):
                 self.super().__init__(nombre,caracteristicas)

class especifica3(dispositivo):
      def __init__(self,nombre,caracteristicas):
                 self.super().__init__(nombre,caracteristicas)
```

y listo ya solo es instanciar y ejecutar algo asi

```
instancia = especifica1("hola",["mi","mundo"])
instancia.imprimir()
```